# Tooltip popup plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, plugin

This plugin displays a tooltip popup with the data obtained via Ajax.  I am sure there are better ones out there, but my objective is to learn how to correctly build a plugin, not find the best one available. I would appreciate any comments, suggestions, criticism from a best practices and design pattern usage perspective.

A live demo is located [here](http://tapmeister.com/test/ajaxTip/index.html).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" /> 
        <title>screenshot</title>  
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <script src="jquery.ajaxTip.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <style type="text/css">

            .myElement{margin:100px;}
            .ajaxToolActive{color:blue;}

            .myAjaxTip {
                border:1px solid #CECECE;
                background:white;
                padding:10px;
                display:none;
                color:black;
                font-size:11px;-moz-border-radius:4px;
                box-shadow: 3px 1px 6px #505050;
                -khtml-border-radius:4px;
                -webkit-border-radius:4px;
                border-radius:4px;
            }
        </style> 

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $('.myElement').ajaxTip({
                    display: function(d){return '<p>'+d.name+'</p><p>'+d.address+'</p><p>'+d.city+', '+d.state+'</p>';},
                    getData:function(){return {id:this.data('id')}},
                    'class':'myAjaxTip'
                });
                $('.destroy').click(function(){$('.myElement').ajaxTip('destroy');});
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p class="myElement" data-id="1" title="ajaxTip Popup">John Doe</p>
        <p class="myElement" data-id="2" title="ajaxTip Popup">Jane Doe</p>
        <p class="myElement" data-id="3" title="ajaxTip Popup">Baby Doe</p>
        <p class="destroy">Destroy</p>
    </body> 
</html> 

/*
* jQuery ajaxTip
* Copyright 2013 Michael Reed
* Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
*/
(function( $ ){

    var methods = {
        init : function( options ) {
            // Create some defaults, extending them with any options that were provided
            var settings = $.extend({
                'url'      : 'getAjaxTip.php',        //To include extra data sent to the server, included it in the url
                'class'    : '', //Class to be added to tooltip (along with class standardAjaxTip)
                'mouseMove': true,      //Whether to move tooltip with mouse
                'speed'    : 'fast',    //fadeIn speed
                'delay'    : 250,       //milliseconds to delay before requesting data from server
                'xOffset'  : 20,
                'yOffset'  : 10,
                'dataType' : 'json',    //Returned data.  Options are json, text, etc
                'getData'  : function(){return {}}, //Use to set additional data to the server
                'display'  : function(data){   //User function must include function(data) {... return string}
                    var string='';
                    for (var key in data) {string+='<p>'+data[key]+'</p>';}
                    return string;
                }
                }, options  || {});     //Just in case user doesn't provide options

            return this.each(function(){
                var showing,title,timeoutID,ajax,$t=$(this).wrapInner('<span />'),ajaxTip;
                $t.children('span').hover(function(e) {
                    if(!showing){
                        title = $t.attr('title');$t.attr('title','');//Prevent title from being displayed,and save for later to put back    
                        timeoutID=window.setTimeout(function() {
                            ajax=$.get( settings.url,settings.getData.call($t),function(data){
                                ajaxTip=$('<div />')
                                .addClass('standardAjaxTip '+settings.class)
                                .html(((title != '')?'<h3>'+title+'</h3>':'')+settings.display(data))
                                .css("top",(e.pageY - settings.yOffset) + "px")
                                .css("left",(e.pageX + settings.xOffset) + "px")
                                .css("position","absolute")
                                .appendTo('body').fadeIn(settings.speed);                    
                                showing = true;
                                $t.addClass('ajaxToolActive');
                                }, settings.dataType);
                            },settings.delay); //Delay before requesting data from server
                    }
                    },
                    function()
                    {
                        //When not hover
                        if (typeof ajax == 'object') {ajax.abort();}
                        window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
                        $t.attr('title',title);    
                        $t.removeClass('ajaxToolActive');
                        if(showing){ajaxTip.remove();}
                        showing = false;
                });

                $t.mousemove(function(e) {
                    if(settings.mouseMove && showing) {ajaxTip.css("top",(e.pageY - settings.yOffset) + "px").css("left",(e.pageX + settings.xOffset) + "px");}
                });
            });
        },

        //Add additional methods as needed
        destroy : function() {
            //console.log('destroy');
            return this.each(function(){
                var $e = $(this);
                $e.html($e.children('span').html());
            })
        },
    };

    $.fn.ajaxTip = function(method) {
        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.ajaxTip' );
        }    
    };


})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code mostly the same with some changes to style and comments:

```
(function($){
    var defaults = {
        'url'      : 'getAjaxTip.php', // The url used to get the tooltip data.
        'class'    : '', // Css class(es) to add to tooltip (along with standardAjaxTip).
        'mouseMove': true, // A flag indicating whether to move tooltip with mouse.
        'speed'    : 'fast', // The speed at which to fade in the tool tip.
        'delay'    : 250, // Delay (in ms) before requesting data from server.
        'xOffset'  : 20,
        'yOffset'  : 10,
        'dataType' : 'json',            
        'getData'  : function () { 
            return {}; 
        },
        // A function to transform the data from the server into an html fragment.
        'display'  : function(data) {   
            var htmlString = '';
            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                htmlString += '<p>' + val + '</p>';
            });
            return htmlString;
        }
    };

    var methods = {
        init : function (options) {
            // Create settings using the defaults extended with any options provided.
            var settings = $.extend(defaults, options  || {});

            return this.each(function () {
                var title,
                    timeoutID,
                    ajax,
                    $t,
                    ajaxTip;

                // Wrap the content of the current element in a span.
                $t = $(this).wrapInner('<span />');

                $t.children('span').hover(function(e) {
                    if(!$t.hasClass('ajaxToolActive')) {
                        title = $t.attr('title');
                        $t.attr('title','');  // Remove the title so that it doesn't show on hover.

                        timeoutID = window.setTimeout(function () {
                            ajax = $.get(settings.url, settings.getData.call($t), function (data) {

                                // Create a div to be the tooltip pop up, add the styling as well as
                                // the html (from the display function) to it and then fade the element in
                                // using the speed specified in the settings.
                                ajaxTip = $('<div />')
                                .addClass('standardAjaxTip ' + settings['class'])
                                .html(((title !== '') ? '<h3>' + title + '</h3>' : '') + settings.display(data))
                                .css('top', (e.pageY - settings.yOffset) + 'px')
                                .css('left', (e.pageX + settings.xOffset) + 'px')
                                .css('position', 'absolute')
                                .appendTo('body')
                                .fadeIn(settings.speed);

                                $t.addClass('ajaxToolActive');
                            }, 
                            settings.dataType);
                        }, settings.delay);
                    }
                },
                function () {
                    // User is no longer hovering so cancel the call to the server and hide the tooltip.
                    if (typeof ajax === 'object') { 
                        ajax.abort(); 
                    }
                    window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
                    $t.attr('title', title);

                    if ($t.hasClass('ajaxToolActive')) {
                        ajaxTip.remove();
                        $t.removeClass('ajaxToolActive');
                    }
                });

                $t.mousemove(function (e) {
                    if (settings.mouseMove && $t.hasClass('ajaxToolActive')) {
                        ajaxTip.css('top', (e.pageY - settings.yOffset) + 'px')
                            .css('left', (e.pageX + settings.xOffset) + 'px');
                    }
                });
            });
        },
        destroy : function () {
            return this.each(function () {
                var $e = $(this);
                $e.html($e.children('span').html());
            });
        }
    };

    $.fn.ajaxTip = function(method) {
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || ! method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.ajaxTip');
        }    
    };
}(jQuery));
```

I think it would also be a good idea to keep lines to 80 characters. I also removed the showing variable and checked to see if the element had the active class instead. The other main thing I change was settings.class to settings['class'] as class is a future reserved word.

Comment: Thanks RobH!  I like your use of using the class instead of variable "showing" as well as creating a new variable "defaults".  I see you didn't define `$t` in the `var` definition as `$(this).wrapInner('<span />');`  Also, you use `===` instead of `==` to check if "ajax" is an object.  May I ask why?

Comment: @user1032531 I decided to split out the definition of $t and the assigning of it to leave a space for a comment as it wasn't obvious to me why you are wrapping it first (I meant to ask!). In JavaScript == and != use type coercion which isn't normally what you want to do so it's good to get into the habit of using === and !== which don't convert types while checking equality. There is a great SO answer on the topic [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/1402923)

Comment: Thanks again Rob,  I really appreciate your time.  I am 100% self taught, and while resources like SO definitely provide me with most of the knowledge I need, having someone look over the final results and critique is is invaluable.  It would be nice to even get a grade!  Maybe A to F for useability, best practices, etc.  By the way, you think I might get a B?

Comment: PS.  I wrapped the `<DIV>` with a `<SPAN>` so that hover is only active when over the text and not the entire row of the block element.  Maybe a hack, but didn't know a better way.  Do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: @user1032531 I don't think it's a bad effort at all. As for the wrapping with a `<span>` - you could style your block elements to be a certain width, or use inline elements instead of your `<p>`s.